# How to extend a REST API beyond normal CRUD operations

Tags: php, api, rest, kohana

I am working on a REST interface for ORM objects for a Kohana website. I've got two controllers so far:

**Controller_Api_Product**

`URL: api.example.com/product/<product_id>`

**Controller_Api_Category**

`URL: api.example.com/category/<category_id>`

Each of these accepts the following methods and updates the record succesfully.

- POST: Create
- GET: Read
- PUT: Update
- DELETE: Delete

I'd like to create a some way of handling ORM's has_many properties. For example I'd like to be able link a product and a category together. I have this relationship stored in a separate table (products_categories). I don't have an ORM model for that table (as I don't store any extra relationship data).

What would be the best way to manage it? Should I create an ORM model for the table and it's own controller?

**Controller_Api_Product_Category**

`URL: api.example/product_category/<product_category_id>`

Should I use a different HTTP method (eg. LINK)?

**Controller_Api_Product_Category** *called with method LINK*

`URL: api.example/product/<product_id>`

Should I have some other completely different controller which isn't bound to a specific model?

**Controller_Api_Link**

`URL: api.example.com/link/product/<product_id>/category/<category_id>`

Having a separate link controller can obviously be used for any objects. I'm just a bit stumped on how to extend my REST API beyond the normal CRUD actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say if you already have a link stored in table, you should use it like any other object?

```
 URL: api.example.com/links/<link_id>
```

and perform CRUD operations on the link itself.

Comment: That sounds right, a controller for each database table (as opposed to ORM model).